# OpenGL Immediate Mode textures not working

Tags: macos, opengl, immediate-mode

I am attempting to build a simple project using immediate mode textures.
Unfortunately, when I render, the GL color shows up rather than the texture.  I've searched around for solutions, but found no meaningful difference between online examples and my code.

I've reduced it to a minimal failing example, which I have provided here.  If my understanding is correct, this should produce a textured quad, with corners of black, red, green, and blue.  Unfortunately, it appears purple, as if it's ignoring the texture completely.  What am I doing wrong?

```
#include <glut.h>

GLuint tex;

void displayFunc() {
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex);
    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP);
    glColor3f(0.5, 0, 1);
    glTexCoord2f(0.0, 0.0);
    glVertex2f(-1.0, -1.0);

    glTexCoord2f(1.0, 0.0);
    glVertex2f(1.0, -1.0);

    glTexCoord2f(0.0, 1.0);
    glVertex2f(-1.0, 1.0);

    glTexCoord2f(1.0, 1.0);
    glVertex2f(1.0, 1.0);
    glEnd();

    glutSwapBuffers();
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGB);
    glutInitWindowPosition(0, 0);
    glutInitWindowSize(640, 480);
    glutCreateWindow("Test");
    glutDisplayFunc(displayFunc);

    GLubyte textureData[] = { 0, 0, 0, 255, 0, 0, 0, 255, 0, 0, 0, 255, 255, 255, 0 };
    GLsizei width = 2;
    GLsizei height = 2;

    glGenTextures(1, &tex);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB8, width, height, 0, GL_RGB8, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, (GLvoid*)textureData);

    glutMainLoop();
}
```

The output:
[image: quad is purple]

Also possibly worth mentioning:

I am building this project on a Mac (running El Capitan 10.11.1)

Graphics card: NVIDIA GeForce GT 650M 1024 MB

Comment: Additionally to Reti Koradi's answer, your texture is also not mipmap-complete. You should explicitely set the texture minification filter to `GL_LINEAR` or `GL_NEAREST` via `glTexParameteri`.

Comment: @derhass Thanks! I needed both that and Reti Koradi's answer to fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're passing an invalid argument to `glTexImage2D()`. `GL_RGB8` is not one of the supported values for the 7th (*format*) argument. The correct value is `GL_RGB`.

Sized formats, like `GL_RGB8`, are used for the *internalFormat* argument. In that case, the value defines both the number of components and the size of each component used for the internal storage of the texture.

The *format* and *type* parameters define the data you pass in. For these, the *format* only defined the number of components, while the *type* defines the type and size of each component.

Whenever you have problems with your OpenGL code, make sure that you call `glGetError()` to check for errors. In this case, you would see a `GL_INVALID_ENUM` error caused by your `glTexImage2D()` call.

Comment: Thanks! That, along with derhass's comment, fixed it.